Why do some JFETs oscillate and others don't?
Below is a simple JFET Clapp Oscillator, which works quite well.  It starts oscillating at around 40us and gets into clean, stable oscillation by 100us:

When I replace the J309 JFET with a more modern MMBF4416A, which says "Designed for RF Amplifiers", the oscillation stops completely, and I get close to 0 gate voltage.  Why?
I looked at several different JFET data sheets and have had trouble deciphering which characteristics are needed for a (good, clean, stable) oscillator - or for any oscillation at all.
Which characteristics of the JFET enable it to function as an oscillator in this case? What should I look for when selecting a JFET in my circuit? Is there a modern SMD JFET that will work as well (or better) than a J309?

Update
Thank you for the responses.  To answer the questions that were raised:

This is an LTspice simulation, with JFET models coming from http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/
My question is: What parameters of the JFET on the datasheet are relevant to making a good oscillator? Looking at different datasheets, what should I look for when building an oscillator? What characteristics cause one to oscillate well and one not to?


Are you talking about the simulation or an actual physical circuit? If it's the simulation, where are you getting your transistor models?

The J309 has a lot higher beta and lambda. Both of which are related to $g_m$. And $g_m$ is very important here. Try changing the beta value to something close to the J309's. Or find a different device with higher beta.

Just looked an there are MMBFJ111-J113 devices available.

It would be nice for OP to become familiar with importance of positive feedback and open-loop gain of an amplifier.

Just change your C1 to 100 pF.

LTspiceXVII includes PN4416 in its default N-channel FET library. It oscillates in OP's circuit quite nicely. Oscillators that start up quickly are not necessarily a "good thing", although oscillators that don't start at all are a disaster. It seems that because spice circuits are approximations, simulations tend to oscillate where real circuits don't, at least in my experience.

@DaveTweed Updated with answers

@Ale..chenski Yes, Barkhausen criteria require open loop gain >= 1, and in this case, there will be slightly more than 50% attenuation, so we need transistor gain >= 2.  Do some JFETs not have that?

@SRobertJames Just take the JFET and ground its drain and gate. Tie the source to 10 V or 15 V. Something like that. And measure the current from the supply. Now do this for the J309 and for the MMBF4416. You want to see something in milliamps, the more the better, and not in microamps. This is called Idss. It could be that the model is bad. It could be the datasheet is wrong. In LTspice I see the J309 shows over 20 mA, while the MMBF4416 shows around 14 uA. The MMBF4416 result doesn't match up with the datasheet you provide. It does for the J309, though. So maybe the LTspice model is wrong.

models and datasheets
The MMBF4416A datasheet you provided is terrible. There are no charts given. Nothing to examine. However, my eye is drawn to this:

If you now set this up in LTspice where \$V_{_\text{CC}}=15\:\text{V}\$ (per datasheet spec):

Note that I downloaded the PSpice model from OnSemi and included its text, as well, adding an X to the model name. This demonstrates that the model from OnSemi for PSpice appears to be the same as the model included in the LTspice library of parts.
Also note that the value of about \$14\:\mu\text{A}\$ is nothing like what the datasheet says.
It turns out that the 2N4416/2N4416A/SST4416 is very much better and does include curves. First, let's look at the \$I_{_\text{DSS}}\$ value:

That matches up with the OnSemi datasheet.
And here's the chart curve of interest:

This definitely disagrees with the results in LTspice using both the internal model as well as the downloaded PSpice model I got from OnSemi.
So this is a problem. If the models are accurate (and the only way to tell is to buy some parts and measure them) then this device won't be useful. It's \$\beta\$ value is simply way too small. If the models are not accurate, then perhaps the device will work fine (you still need to buy some and verify) and somehow a very bad Spice model has been propagated (cargo cult-like.)
I don't know the reality here. But I can see problems, already. The Spice models won't support the circuit. But the real device may do fine. I just can't tell without having some to test.
simulating your circuit
The first thing I need to do is to figure out what to expect from the circuit, by theory. Here's what I find:
solve(Eq(1/I/omega/470e-12 + 1/I/omega/470e-12 + 1/I/omega/(47e-12+18.5e-12)+I*omega*10e-6,0),omega)
[-44184267.2469006, 44184267.2469006]
(44184267.2469006/2/pi).n()
7032144.53923756

So I'm expecting to see about \$7\:\text{MHz}\$ as the oscillation frequency.
The impedance, looking into the \$C_1\$/\$C_2\$ node of your circuit is:
Freq or omega (add 'j'): 7e6
470pF|(470pF+47pF+18.5pF+10uH)
-j46.6668025, 46.6668025 < -90

Which tells me that the impedance of the remaining inductor (\$L_1\$ in your circuit) needs to be about \$10\times\$ that much, which at this frequency means \$10\:\mu\text{H}\$. That's quite a bit smaller than what you used. By a rule of thumb that also means \$R_1=470\:\Omega\$. (You aren't far from it, there.)
I will use my values for your \$R_1\$ and \$L_1\$, not your values. I'm also adding a semi-necessary diode (and eliminating your grid/gate leak self-bias resistor):

The indicated \$f\approx 6.95\:\text{MHz}\$ is very close to my calculations above. I'm calling it good.
Now, I'll apply the PSpice model, which we already know won't work well. However, since I already know that the \$\beta\$ is way way too low, the impedance of \$L_1\$ (your circuit, not mine) and \$R_1\$ does need to be increased a lot. I'll multiply both of them by about 50 to get the inductor value back to where you had it. But your \$R_1\$ will be higher than you used:

The frequency is still about the same. But the signal's peak-to-peak is almost non-existent. The PSpice model's \$\beta\$ is just pathetic.
I'll change that, now, while returning your \$R_1\$ and \$L_1\$ back to the values I calculated earlier:

So, it is the \$\beta\$ parameter that is the problem. And as I wrote before, without parts in hand I cannot tell you much about the reality of using that part. I don't know whether the models provided are wrong or the datasheet is wrong. (Probably the model. But I don't know.)

Made with microcap v12, interactive mode "Stability" analysis.
Just change your C1. It will start to oscillate within 250 us ...
Tried until 420 MHz.



JFETs have very spready DC characteristics .I have not used them in any high volume products due to fear of a production disaster. Sure people do and seem to get away with it .Try reducing R1 to get more gain so it will start.I always place a reverse 1n4148 gate to ground to help stabilise amplitude on low volume car radio local oscillator because you want good starting but not too much overall gain because this will distort the output waveform and give bad stability .The diode allows more room for spreads in gain.
